# list index out of range while executing path finding function

Tags: python, indexoutofboundsexception, path-finding

I'm trying to create a list of all possible paths from a given point on a graph to another. the graph is laid out on a 5x6 grid, with spaces b1 and c1 missing. when executing a function to find all paths, I'm encountering an index error when the function executes on any of the 6 row spaces. I'm unsure how to correct this as I don't see how the index can be out of range since it's self referential.

```
class Graph: 

def __init__(self, vertices): 
    # No. of vertices 
    self.V = vertices  
      
    # default dictionary to store graph 
    self.graph = defaultdict(list)  

# function to add an edge to graph 
def addEdge(self, u, v): 
    self.graph[u].append(v) 
    
    

'''A recursive function to print all paths from 'u' to 'd'. 
visited[] keeps track of vertices in current path. 
path[] stores actual vertices and path_index is current 
index in path[]'''
def printAllPathsUtil(self, u, d, visited, path): 

    # Mark the current node as visited and store in path 
    visited[u]= True
    path.append(u) 

    # If current vertex is same as destination, then print 
    # current path[] 
    if u == d: 
        print (path) 
    else: 
        # If current vertex is not destination 
        # Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex 
        for i in self.graph[u]: 
            if visited[i]== False: 
                self.printAllPathsUtil(i, d, visited, path) 
                  
    # Remove current vertex from path[] and mark it as unvisited 
    path.pop() 
    visited[u]= False


# Prints all paths from 's' to 'd' 
def printAllPaths(self, s, d): 

    # Mark all the vertices as not visited 
    visited =[False]*(self.V) 

    # Create an array to store paths 
    path = [] 

    # Call the recursive helper function to print all paths 
    self.printAllPathsUtil(s, d, visited, path)
```

here's the graph:

```
g = Graph()
g.addEdge(3,1)
g.addEdge(6,2)

g.addEdge(3,4)
g.addEdge(5,4)
g.addEdge(5,6)
g.addEdge(4,3)
g.addEdge(4,5)
g.addEdge(6,5)

g.addEdge(7,3)
g.addEdge(8,4)
g.addEdge(9,5)
g.addEdge(10,6)

g.addEdge(7,8)
g.addEdge(8,9)
g.addEdge(9,10)
g.addEdge(8,7)
g.addEdge(9,8)
g.addEdge(10,9)

g.addEdge(11,7)
g.addEdge(12,8)
g.addEdge(13,9)
g.addEdge(14,10)

g.addEdge(11,12)
g.addEdge(12,13)
g.addEdge(13,14)
g.addEdge(12,11)
g.addEdge(13,12)
g.addEdge(14,13)

g.addEdge(15,11)
g.addEdge(16,12)
g.addEdge(17,13)
g.addEdge(18,14)

g.addEdge(15,16)
g.addEdge(16,17)
g.addEdge(17,18)
g.addEdge(16,15)
g.addEdge(17,16)
g.addEdge(18,17)

g.addEdge(19,15)
g.addEdge(20,16)
g.addEdge(21,17)
g.addEdge(22,18)

g.addEdge(19,20)
g.addEdge(20,21)
g.addEdge(21,22)
g.addEdge(20,19)
g.addEdge(21,20)
g.addEdge(22,21)

g.addEdge(1,0)
g.addEdge(4,0)
g.addEdge(5,0)
g.addEdge(2,0)
#name nodes
a1=1; d1=2; a2=3; b2=4;c2=5;d2=6;a3=7;b3=8;c3=9;d3=10;a4=11;b4=12;c4=13;d4=14;a5=15;b5=16;c5=17;d5=18;a6=19;b6=20;c6=21;d6=22;door=0
```

And finally the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-885dbfadd65a> in <module>
----> 1 g.printAllPaths(a6, door)

<ipython-input-61-eecc5a16716f> in printAllPaths(self, s, d)
     50 
     51         # Call the recursive helper function to print all paths
---> 52         self.printAllPathsUtil(s, d, visited, path)

<ipython-input-61-eecc5a16716f> in printAllPathsUtil(self, u, d, visited, path)
     33             for i in self.graph[u]:
     34                 if visited[i]== False:
---> 35                     self.printAllPathsUtil(i, d, visited, path)
     36 
     37         # Remove current vertex from path[] and mark it as unvisited

<ipython-input-61-eecc5a16716f> in printAllPathsUtil(self, u, d, visited, path)
     33             for i in self.graph[u]:
     34                 if visited[i]== False:
---> 35                     self.printAllPathsUtil(i, d, visited, path)
     36 
     37         # Remove current vertex from path[] and mark it as unvisited

<ipython-input-61-eecc5a16716f> in printAllPathsUtil(self, u, d, visited, path)
     32             # Recur for all the vertices adjacent to this vertex
     33             for i in self.graph[u]:
---> 34                 if visited[i]== False:
     35                     self.printAllPathsUtil(i, d, visited, path)
     36 

IndexError: list index out of range
```

is this related to the 6th row having fewer indices? the output prior to the error seems to successfully list all paths, but the error interrupts the function from continuing past the sixth row of the first column.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No idea why this worked, but adding an additional two vertices with directional indices from 0 has solved this problem. I'd still love some advice as to why that eliminated the error as I'm completely in the dark.